RabbitMQ: "All stable feature flags must be enabled after completing an upgrade." - How to fix?
I have just installed RabbitMQ on a fresh Windows 11 installation and enabled the management plugin by running the command rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management in the RabbitMq command prompt.
When I navigate to the RabbitMQ management website in my browser I see the following message:

What is the cause of this error message? And how do I fix the issue?
I'm using RabbitMQ version 3.13.3 with Erlang 27.0. I have not yet created any queues or users in RabbitMQ.
Edit: When I run the command rabbitmqctl list_feature_flags I get the message Error: {:badrpc, :nodedown}. So I can't simply list and enable feature flags.

The issue turned out to be twofold.

The first part of the issue was that I could not simply run the command rabbitmqctl list_feature_flags to see what feature flags were enabled or not. The command would return the error Error: {:badrpc, :nodedown}. Running the command rabbitmqctl status revealed the error: TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed, which has a solution here. I needed to synchronize the Erlang cookies and then the rabbitmqctl status command worked fine.
After fixing the Erlang cookie synchronization, the command rabbitmqctl list_feature_flags works fine and lists enabled/disabled features. It was then a simple matter of enabling features with the command rabbitmqctl enable_feature_flag <feature_name>. See more documentation on enabling features in the docs.


For Windows Server 2019 Standard Edition (could be similar for other versions)

There Should be some shortcuts on the startup menu go and find the folder called RabbitMq Server.
In this folder use RabbitMQ Service - stop to stop service.
Copy .erlang.cookie From C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile
Paste .erlang.cookie to %USERPROFILE%
Start service from shortcut RabbitMQ Service - start
After this click on RabbitMQ Command Prompt (sbin dir) this will open a cmd file and locate the folder of RabbitMq Server location
type rabbitmqctl.bat status and check for Erlang error. if the error is gone you have achieved the hard part.
now type rabbitmqctl.bat list_feature_flags after this you will see some features are disabled and most of them are enabled.
To enable these features, type rabbitmqctl.bat enable_feature _flag detailed_queues_endpoint
Congratulations you have successfully fixed the issue. In http://localhost:15672/ the error should be gone.

